# Is it true that $\{x^4+y^3+z^2:\ x,y,z\in\mathbb Q_{\ge0}\}=\mathbb Q_{\ge0}$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

Let $\mathbb Q_{\ge0}$ be the set of all nonnegative rational numbers. I have the following conjecture based on my computation.

**4-3-2 Conjecture.** Each $r\in\mathbb Q_{\ge0}$ can be written as $x^4+y^3+z^2$ with $x,y,z\in\mathbb Q_{\ge0}$.

As $m/n=(mn^{11})/n^{12}$ for any integers $m\ge0$ and $n>0$, it suffices to consider the 4-3-2 conjecture with $r\in\mathbb N=\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$. For example,
\begin{align}2^{12}\times7=&2^4+15^3+159^2,
\\4^{12}\times75=&122^4+1007^3+3951^2,
\\3^{12}\times1140=&0^4+531^3+21357^2,
\\5^{12}\times23710=&217^4+17897^3+232166^2.
\end{align}
For each $n=1,\ldots,30000$ with $n\not=23710$, I have found a number $m\in\{1,2,3,4\}$ such that $m^{12}n=x^4+y^3+z^2$ for some $x,y,z\in\mathbb N$.

**QUESTIONS.** Is the 4-3-2 conjecture true? Any way to prove it?

Your comments are welcome!

Comment: Did you try numeric studies find any nonnegative integer with no 4-3-2 integer representation? You claim you needed $m=1,2,3,4$, can this set be reduced (on the bounded segment)?

Comment: If $m=1$ or $m=2$ is okay for $n$, then so is $m=4$. For $n=75$, $m$ cannot be $3$. For $n=1140$, $m$ cannot be $4$. For $n=23710$, $m$ must be greater than $4$. For more data, you may visit https://oeis.org/A350714 . For $n\le 40000$, we may require $m\le 4$ with the only exception $n=23710$ for which we may take $m=5$.

Comment: @Ilya Bogdanov In 2015 I conjectured that $\{x^4-y^3+z^2:\ x,y,z=1,2,3,\ldots\}=\mathbb Z$. See https://oeis.org/A266152 .

Comment: Another related conjecture of mine states that each integer $n>1$ can be written as $x^4+y^3+z^2+2^k$ with $x,y,z\in\mathbb N$ and $k\in\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$. See https://oeis.org/A280356 .

Comment: For $n=30000,\ldots,10^5$, there is a number $m\in\{1,2,3,4\}$ such that $m^{12}n=x^4+y^3+z^2$ for some $x,y,z\in\mathbb N$. I verified this for $30000\le n\le 40000$ and $77000\le n\le 10^5$, and Qing-Hu Hou checked this for $40000<n<77000$.

Comment: Prof. Qing-Hu Hou has extended the verification of the 4-3-2 conjecture for $r\in\mathbb  N$ with $r\le2\times10^5$.

Comment: [Roth](https://academic.oup.com/jlms/article-abstract/s1-24/1/4/874713?redirectedFrom=fulltext) has proven that almost all positive integers are of the form $x^4+y^3+z^2$ with $x,y,z$ positive integers.